# Using a parameter for the function to call

Tags: postgresql

Within PostgresSQL how can I define a parameter as a function, i.e.

```
SELECT MAX(value) FROM table;
SELECT MIN(value) FROM table;
SELECT AVG(value) FROM table;
```

where the function is a parameter, something like the following:

```
SELECT $1(value) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. Use multiple separate queries, and choose the one to execute. If you have to do this within SQL, you can also [do the choosing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) depending on a parameter:

```
SELECT (CASE $1::text
  WHEN 'max' THEN (SELECT MAX(value) FROM table)
  WHEN 'min' THEN (SELECT MIN(value) FROM table)
  WHEN 'avg' THEN (SELECT AVG(value) FROM table)
END);
```